# Focus in Calendar Component

Tags: java-me, lwuit

What should I do to focus on the specific date in calendar component?

I am not talking about indicator here. **calendar.setCurrentDate()** and **calendar.setSelectedDate()** gets the indicator on the date, but focus is always on date of 1st sunday. I have read on net that this functionality is not provided by calendar yet. Do any one have any idea? Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can derive calendar and override `updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton, int currentMonth, int day)`.

Here you can perform a `requestFocus()` invocation when the specific date matches your requirement.

Comment: Hey Shai Almog, can you provide some sample code? I had seen on some site your updated calendar class with fix of this bug but i could not get that jar so still stuck with this problem, please help me.

Comment: All of our improvements are in SVN and unavailable as JAR's. You will need to download the LWUIT SVN sources and build them to get the latest LWUIT with all the new features. See the source link at http://lwuit.java.net/